# Why does this query not work?

Tags: mysql

```
 SELECT * FROM leads WHERE researcher_id=66 AND WHERE YEARWEEK(entry_date)=YEARWEEK(now())
```

Can YEARWEEK not be combined with a regular ID query??
Is there some other brackets or re-arranging I need for this?

Basically I want to return all the leads generated by a researcher for the current week.

Answer (score 4):

```
--modify researcher_id=66 AND WHERE researcher_id=66 AND  
SELECT * FROM leads WHERE researcher_id=66 AND  YEARWEEK(entry_date)=YEARWEEK(now())
```

Comment: OMG!!!..I can't believe I have been so stupid for the last hour....this is embarrasing

Comment: We've all been there man, trust me.  Some of us on a daily basis.

Comment: This is normal, I have frequently